# angular 1.5 code structure with import confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

This is the index file that intend to load all modules into app.js

https://github.com/kitconcept/webpack-starter-angular/blob/master/src/common/common.js

codes:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import Navbar from './navbar/navbar';
import Hero from './hero/hero';
import User from './user/user';

export default angular.module('app.common', [
  Navbar.name,
  Hero.name,
  User.name
]);
```

But where does the User.name come from? in users/user.js there's no name property

https://github.com/kitconcept/webpack-starter-angular/blob/master/src/common/user/user.js

codes :

```
import angular from 'angular';
import UserFactory from './user.factory';

let userModule = angular.module('user', [])

.factory('User', UserFactory);

export default userModule;
```

I'm lost in this boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

`factory` method accepts `name` as a first argument. Also, please include code samples in your question besides of posting links because link might get broken in future.

Comment: is this build in angular?

Comment: Yes, factory is built in angular module

Comment: I didn't know factory method accept name as first argument. How can User has `name` as property? how does that work I'm confused, I know factory but I didn't know u can do Factory.name.

Comment: Well, `name` call to a factory/service is not listed anywhere in angular documentation. You can find out all factory API capabilities only by taking a look into source code

Comment: wow that sock me a little bit. So how usually people important factory base on above case? What would u do Slava?